# How do I stop \usepackage{graphicx} pushing my whole document down?

Tags: spacing, graphics

After I load the graphics package and create a pdf I get my image to appear perfectly but my page numbers are now basically on the very bottom of every page and the text on each page has shifted down with them.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Graphics sets the pdf page size. Add a correct paper option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do you have an example of what a correct paper option would be? Thanks, this is what I already have at the start of my paper                                                              \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.0cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0cm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\parskip 0.1in
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

Comment: Try `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should modify the layout of the page with the `geometry` package. The  different parameters are not independent, and `geometry`  takes care of that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that worked perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to answer or do you have a dupe at hand?

Comment: @Johannes_B http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152249/graphicx-or-graphics-package-distorts-format/169323#169323

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Voted.