# Graphicx package is shrinking memoir pages?

Tags: memoir

I need to format my book to 6x9 for printing on KDP. In my mwe, when I include `graphicx` the page shrinks as shown below. The pages layout is fine when I remove the line `\usepackages{graphicx}` or the `\usepackage{geometry}` line.

How do I format my book for 6x9 using memoir and graphicx?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, bindingoffset=0.75in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load `geometry` after `graphicx` (see this [answer by @David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169323/273733) as to why this happens I think):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, bindingoffset=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great, tho shouldn't the bindingoffset be removed? It puts the wide margin on the inside when it should be on the outside.

Comment: Hi James I'm just saying that your code `\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}` without `bindingoffset=0.75in` did the trick. `bindingoffset=0.75in` pushed the text too far to the outside of the page.